# change the access mode of a workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on vba and I would like to know how to change the access mode of a workbook that is open in read-only mode in read/write mode and continue with other instructions afterwards.
I managed to change the access mode except that it does not execute the following as instructions. 
Thank you.

```
Sub RW()
   If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
       ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
       ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite
   End If

   MsgBox "ok"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try going through your code using F8, and see if code is entering the Condition or not

Comment: Also Change your `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`, it could be that they are referring to different workbooks, and you are not able to see the results.

Answer (score 2):

More Sophisticated Version of your Code:

Take a look at the info present at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changefileaccess) about the function `.ChangeFileAccess`.

```
Sub RW()

   If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then

      MsgBox "Access Changed from Read Only to Read/Write"
      ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
      ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite

   Else: MsgBox "No Access Changed"

   End If

End Sub
```

I think the issue should be with `Activeworkbook` & `Thisworkbook`

- Another Suggestion ... Read About [**Personal MacroWorkbook**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566), and try and save this code in that, so you can use it efficiently and by defining proper references.

Comment: Note that according to the documentation, the [Workbook.ChangeFileAccess method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changefileaccess) needs to re-load the workbook. That means code excecution stops right after the `ChangeFileAccess` (it closes the current instance of the workbook to re-load it) and therefore the `MsgBox` after this line will never show up.

Comment: Also unless this code is in a Excel Add-In I recommend to use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. `ThisWorkbook` is more reliable because it is the workbook the code is running in (and it cannot change) while `ActiveWorkbook` can easily change by a users click, because it is the workbook that has the focus (is on top) while this code runs.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changefileaccess) in its "Workbook.ChangeFileAccess Method" when you switch from a workbook that is opened ReadOnly to ReadWrite, that Excel needs to retrieve a new copy of the same workbook from disk, thus opening a new version of the file.

Given that this is the case, you would need to implement the code in the On_Open procedure of your workbook. Because this is the case, you will need to inform the user prior to doing the procedure that the status will be changed.

Note: if someone openes the workbook after it is sent in an email (just as an example) or any other way in which the file is not yet saved on disk, this may cause an error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then

        MsgBox "Access will be changed from Read Only to Read/Write." & _
            vbNewLine & "The file will reopen in ReadWrite mode."

      ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
      ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite

   Else: MsgBox "No Access Changed"

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything in my opinion. After the'if' block if you put in more instructions it won't work. Look carefully at my code there is an Msgbox "ok" after the condition that is made after and that's my problem

Comment: @mordiop that is because `ChangeFileAccess` has to re-load the file to change the mode. That means the current file is closed at the `ChangeFileAccess` line and therefore code excecution is *immediatley* aborted at this point. The rest of the code will never run. So the `ChangeFileAccess` is the very last line this code will ever be able to run. Anything after it cannot run. This is by design and cannot be changed.

Comment: Okay, I understand. However, is there a way to manage the access competition of the binder?
I have five users who use it and each one makes his own changes.
my idea was to open the file read-only and at closing change the read/write access mode to apply the changes.

Comment: @mordiop Excel is not a database (which can be accessed by multiple users simultaneously). You might want to use a real database (eg SQL) or at least MS Access then.

Comment: @mordiop If you want to have several people working on the same file you need to use the 365 shared access feature. Or you create an access backend... but it's difficult to know whether that would work for you without knowing what the changes are.